# error including files with file_get_contents()

Tags: php, wordpress, opencart, file-get-contents

on a project i'm working on, for different reasons i had to separate the footer/header from the main site, so let's say that these 2 files are in a folder called *shared/* (this path is inside the root), so i can access to each file from **http://domain.com/shared/footer.php**

then i have the rest of the site (content), these files that print the content use file_get_contents() to get the header/footer, but file_get_content() returns false, i don't use include/require functions because the footer/header has it's own functionality and it's possible that will break something if i use include/require.

the weird thing is that if i add a to the header/footer:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

it works perfect, but of curse shows some notices on the footer/header code, i don't know why if i disable the error reporting doesn't work.

some code in my application:

```
echo file_get_contents('http://mydomain.com/shared/header.php');
```

my header.php is simple html, when i try this way, file_get_contents() return false

```
<!doctype html>
```

to make it work i have to add this to header.php, now file_get_contents() get the file and show the html, but of curse with notices

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
<!doctype html>
```

Comment: if f_g_c() returns false then the file you've specified isn't readable, or doesn't exist. And note that f_g_c() does *NOT* execute any code found in the file you're fetching. that's why include/require exist.

Comment: @MarcB as i specified i can't use require/include and if i enable error logs on the header/footer f_g_c() read the file

Comment: welp, with only vague symptons and no code at all, we can't help you.

Comment: i think i easy to understand the problem reading, but anyway i added some code @MarcB thanks in advance

Comment: you're doing a local http request. That is just INSANE. why not just `file_get_contents('shared/header.php')`?

Comment: A lot of shared hosts have trouble communicating to themselves via HTTP (weird DNS, that sort of thing). You should develop your app in a way that does **not** require local HTTP communication

Comment: because in that way it will work like include/require, the thing is, these files (header/footer) has it's own functionality and can't be mixed the rest of the site @MarcB

Comment: interesting, it might be something with my local config, thanks @Phil

Comment: just checked and allow_url_fopen is enable :/ @Phil

Comment: If your code doesn't work when using include or require then that itself is a problem. You should be looking into fixing that instead of attempting to bypass the problem.

Comment: @RommelCastro I didn't suggest that was a problem. What I did suggest was that it was a name lookup issue. There's a good chance your host doesn't know how to communicate with itself by its externally visible hostname. You would have similar (bad) luck using `localhost` as that would probably fail a named virtual-host match. In short, this is probably something that cannot be worked around using your current application approach.

Comment: @NathanDawson i get your point, but let's say that header/footer is one application, and the rest of the site is part of another application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, i fixed this with this function and it works perfect! :D

```
function get_include_contents($filename) {
 if (is_file($filename)) {
    ob_start();
    include $filename;
    $contents = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $contents;
 }
 return false;
}
```

Comment: `return ob_get_clean();`